# How to insert quote character (") as an element of URL in importXML function?

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

My URL contains a quote character, and Google Spreadsheets see this as the end of the URL whereas it is not.

```
https://api.archives-ouvertes.fr/search/?fq=producedDateY_i:[2013 TO 2015]&fq=docType_s:"ART"&rows=0
```

How can I use an URL with `ImportXML()` that has a quote character in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the quote character, instead of `"` use `""""`.

Another alternative is to put the URL alone on cell, lets say A1, then put the cell reference in your formula:

```
  =IMPORTXML(A1,"//div")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also encode your url. `%22` is the encoded quotations:

```
https://api.archives-ouvertes.fr/search/?fq=producedDateY_i:[2013%20TO%202015]&fq=docType_s:%22ART%22&rows=0
```